# Como colocar um link para baixar o aplicativo quando o usuário entrar no meu site pelo celular

Tags: android, wordpress, ios

Bom, tenho um site e o aplicativo para IOS e Android. E queria que toda vez que o usuário entrasse pelo smartphone ele tivesse a opção de baixar o aplicativo, e já reconhecesse qual sistema operacional ele está. Como no http://www.mercadolivre.com.br/
Mas não acho tutorial nenhum sobre como fazer isso.
Uso o wordpress no desenvolvimento do meu site e também não achei plugins para fazer isso!

Comment: Para Wordpress eu usei este plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/appbanners/ Funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 6):

Para iOS, você pode utilizar o [Smart App Banner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

Basta adicionar a metatag

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

---

Para Android não tem nada oficial do Google, mas você pode utilizar o [jquery.smartbanner](https://github.com/jasny/jquery.smartbanner)

Comment: Para IOS deu certo, mas para android não deu.